# Message passing between page to extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

So I have script that does not execute on webpage only work in extension,

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("exe");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (strUser == "note") {
            chrome.extension.connectNative('note');
        }
        if (strUser == "calc") {
            chrome.extension.connectNative('calc');
        }
    });
```

I understand the logic but I lack experience to do it. As far as I understand I need to pass my script function to `html` page via message passing but I can't do it. I have no clue.eq

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you mean by this question. Are you trying to execute this in an extension? What is the problem then?

Comment: no i want to execute it via button in webpage for example in my localhost when i click button on page without clicking extension i want to execute it but it does not work.This is my last question related to this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745405/native-messaging-extension-connectnative-not-working-on-localhost?noredirect=1#comment51496569_31745405

Comment: @Xan  this is what i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.extension` is, *unsurprisingly*, only available to extension code. By the way, you should be really using `chrome.runtime.connectNative`, but the same applies.

You have 2 broad options:

1. Add a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to the page, let it add a click listener, and then pass the request to your background page. Content scripts can communicate with your background, but cannot execute `connectNative` themselves.
2. If this is for a fixed website, you can make the website itself send a message to the extension's background page. This uses `externally_connectable` and is explained [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Again, you'll need a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (on an [event script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)) to handle requests to launch something, as this is the only thing that's both (1) privileged enough to do it, (2) always available to process the request.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but what is fixed website?what is the difference between .extension and .runtime i assume .extension only work when you click extension and runtime work when you open page?my content script will ask for extension code on background page is it possible to send function from background to content script with request?

Comment: "Fixed" means "an address known in advance, not any site", because `externally_connectable` requires a match pattern with a second-level domain in it. There are some functions duplicated in `extension` and `runtime`, but messaging functions in `extension` are considered deprecated - you should use `runtime`.

Comment: And I would recommend a read through the [Messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to see what they can do. The idea would be to send a message containing the option you want, e.g. `{"exec": strUser}`, and decide what to do on the background side.

Comment: but strUser is just a variable i need to connect native host  and thats only possible with extension code is there anyway to pass this to webpage?

Comment: You're not making much sense. The only thing that would not work in that code you posted is `connectNative` - this must be done in the background page. Your task then is to replace it with sending a request to background.

Comment: okay i need to request connectNative function right? and i will replace it with empty box

Comment: I will not help any further. I don't see you understanding my instructions, I can barely understand your questions, and you're turning into a [help vampire](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm). I'm trying to explain on high level what you're supposed to do, but I will not help with implementation. This is not the purpose of Stack Overflow, unless you can narrow down your problems to a [well-written question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Again, there's nothing wrong with asking a question, but you must make sure it's [a _good_ one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Ideally, SO is not about helping you, but about helping others as well who have a similar question. Your questions so far are not very good - you should work on improving them. Think, "can others find my question if they have a similar problem"? It's a bit of SEO, really. Also, you should spend a bit more time doing research before asking, and demonstrate the effort - it does not help if you can't understand the answer, and we don't know what you understand

Comment: yes you are right i need to be more clear and specific for other people who have same question but i did alot research before asking this and all answers are closebox not clear they mention a technique but its hard to find info about that